# Absolute value of limit

Tags: limits, absolute-value

Expain why the following is true:

If $$\lim_ {x\to a}\ f(x) = k$$

then

$$\lim_ {x\to a}\ |f|(x) = |k|$$

Comment: What is the definition of $|f|$? What do you know about continuity.

Comment: I only know that the limit is finite.

Comment: |f| is the absolute value of f

Comment: Do you think that it is a continuous function? If yes, what can you say about the limit?

Comment: So try to learn about limits of continuous functions.

Comment: Split the proof into three cases, $k>0$, $k=0$ and $k<0$.

Comment: Regarding your question, f is a continuous function.

Comment: can't i solve this with sqrt?

Comment: e.g. saying f(x) -> sqrt(f(x))^2 -> |f(x)| or I am wrong?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547122/if-lim-x-to-x-0-fx-l-then-lim-x-to-x-0-lvert-fx-rvert-lver

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma**: For any $a,b\in\Bbb R,$ we have $\bigl||a|-|b|\bigr|\le|a-b|.$

**Proof**: On the one hand, we have by triangle inequality that $$|a|-|b|=|(a-b)+b|-|b|\le|a-b|+|b|-|b|=|a-b|.$$ On the other hand, we likewise have $|b|-|a|\le|b-a|.$ Since $|b|-|a|=-(|a|-|b|)$ and $|b-a|=|a-b|,$ then we have $\pm(|a|-|b|)\le|a-b|,$ and so $\bigl||a|-|b|\bigr|\le|a-b|.$ $\Box$

**Hint**: See if you can apply the Lemma above, together with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of function limits. What do you *know*? What are you *trying to show*? How can the Lemma bridge the gap?

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I will try my best.

Comment: If you get stuck, or aren't sure if you've done something right, feel free to ask me. (I may be eating dinner, but I'll reply when I can.)

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to bug people a lot with my problems and the fact I diden't study enough to solve them on my own...