# If $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x \to x_0} \lvert f(x)\rvert = \lvert L \rvert$.

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

If $\lim_{x \to x0} f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x \to x0} \lvert f(x)\rvert = \lvert L \rvert$.

I know this is true, because $\lvert f(x) \rvert - \lvert L \rvert <= \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \epsilon$ but why is it bigger than minus Epsilon?

Comment: Use again the triangle inequality in the other  direction.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the fact that
$$\vert \vert a \vert - \vert b \vert \vert \leq \vert a - b \vert$$
for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. So if $\vert x - x_0 \vert < \delta$, then
$$\vert \vert f(x) - \vert L \vert \vert \leq \vert f(x) - L \vert < \epsilon,$$
i.e. $\lim_{x \to x_0}\vert f(x) \vert = \vert L \vert$.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the other side of the triangle inequality

$$\epsilon > \vert f(x) - L \vert = \vert L - f(x) \vert \geq \vert L \vert - \vert f(x) \vert \implies -\epsilon < \vert f(x) \vert - \vert L \vert$$